# Return true if array contains object with specific id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array called filters that contain objects. In each object there is an id and another array with objects called filterItems. How can I check to see if one of the filter objects contains a specific filterItems (e.g. if filterItems contains id "Free Cancellation")?

```
const filters = [
  {
    id: 'rateTypeFilter'
    filterItems: [
      {
        id: 'Free Cancellation'
      },
      {
        id: 'Pay Now'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'fuelTypeFilter',
    filterItems: [
      {
        id: 'Gasoline'
      },
      {
        id: 'Hybrid'
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Comment: `filters.some(filter => filter.filterItems.some(item => item.id === 'whatever'))`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: @Michael Don't take it too personally, it just means it doesn't suit [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :) Try to share your attempts and explain where you're stuck at next time. Voting looks rude indeed, but it really isn't, it's just about content filtering.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
filters.some(obj => obj.filterItems.some(v => v.id === "Free Cancellation")) // true
```

Or, if you want the specific object, use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the outside:

```js
filters.find(obj => obj.filterItems.some(v => v.id === "Free Cancellation"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) two times:

```js
const filters = [
  {
    id: 'rateTypeFilter',
    filterItems: [
      {
        id: 'Free Cancellation'
      },
      {
        id: 'Pay Now'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'fuelTypeFilter',
    filterItems: [
      {
        id: 'Gasoline'
      },
      {
        id: 'Hybrid'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const result = filters.some(({ filterItems }) => filterItems.some(({ id }) => id === 'Free Cancellation'));

console.log(result);
```